# Date sequence with negative by

Tags: r, date

How do I get a sequence of monthly dates that *ends* on a given month and has a given length? `seq(as.Date(*), length, by="month")` assumes the start date is given, not the end date, and AFAIK it's impossible to specify a negative value for `by` in this case.

ETA: that is, I want a sequence that spans a given period, but one whose end point is specified rather than the start point. So, something like `seq(to="2000-03-01", len=3, by="month") --> 2000-01-01, 2000-02-01, 2000-03-01`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
rev(seq(as.Date("2000-03-01"), length = 3, by = "-1 month"))
## [1] "2000-01-01" "2000-02-01" "2000-03-01"
```

Comment: Argh! I can't believe I missed the bit "This can optionally be preceded by a (positive or negative) integer" in `?seq.Date`.

Answer (score 6):

```
library(lubridate)
ymd('2011-03-03') - months(0:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could just compute it forward, using `by=month` as the *+1* increment, and then reverse:

```
R> rev(seq(as.Date("2011-01-01"), length=6, by="month"))
[1] "2011-06-01" "2011-05-01" "2011-04-01" "2011-03-01" "2011-02-01" "2011-01-01"
```

Comment: Thanks Dirk, but that's not quite what I'm after. In your example, it would be more like `2010-08-01 2010-09-01 2010-10-01 2010-11-01 2010-12-01 2011-01-01`.

Comment: Right, Gabor has the right answer. I had forgotten about that bit too.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Base functions only:

```
 last.days.of.month <- function(dt) {ldt<- as.POSIXlt(dt)
                                              ldt$mon <- ldt$mon+1
                                              ldt$mday <- 1
                                     return(format( ldt -1, "%Y-%m-%d"))}
 last.days.of.month(as.Date(c("2010-01-06","2010-03-06", "2010-02-06"))  )
# [1] "2010-01-31" "2010-03-31" "2010-02-28"

 seq.ldom <- function(dt, nmonths) {ldt<- rep(as.POSIXlt(dt)[1], nmonths) 
                                    ldt$mon <- ldt$mon+seq(1:nmonths)
                                    ldt$mday <- 1
                        return(format( ldt -1, "%Y-%m-%d"))}
 seq.ldom(as.Date("2010-01-06"), 5)
#[1] "2010-01-31" "2010-02-28" "2010-03-31" "2010-04-30"
#[5] "2010-05-31"
```

Oh, for some reason I thought you wanted the last days of the month. Sorry about the useless code. The first days of the month is not hard.

```
seq.fdom <- function(dt, nmonths) {ldt<- rep(as.POSIXlt(dt)[1], nmonths) 
                                        ldt$mon <- ldt$mon+seq(0:(nmonths-1))
                                        ldt$mday <- 1
                            return(format( ldt , "%Y-%m-%d"))}
seq.fdom(as.Date("2010-01-06"), 5)
#[1] "2010-02-01" "2010-03-01" "2010-04-01" "2010-05-01"
#[5] "2010-06-01"
```

And getting the prior months either:

```
seq.prior.fdom <- function(dt, nmonths) {ldt<- rep(as.POSIXlt(dt)[1], nmonths) 
                                         ldt$mon <- ldt$mon-rev(0:(nmonths-1))
                                         ldt$mday <- 1
                             return(format( ldt , "%Y-%m-%d"))}
      seq.prior.fdom(as.Date("2010-01-06"), 5)
#[1] "2009-09-01" "2009-10-01" "2009-11-01" "2009-12-01"
#[5] "2010-01-01"
```

I think the basic principle is clear (if not beaten to death with a canoe paddle.)